# Difference between be supposed to and ought to

Tags: modal-verbs

I was confused by usage of be supposed to and ought to modals. Where can we use them? For instance, *I am supposed to/ought to learn English today*. I don't have to learn english today, but to me it would be very useful if I learned English today because I could improme my skill. I suspuect that ought to is more suitable here, isn't it?

Another example, *I ought to/am supposed to meet my friend in the railway station today*. Here is more suitable am supposed to, because it would be amoral if I didn't meet my friend, especially if ti has been arranged earlier.

Is it correct? I'd like you explain me those constructions in details, please :)

Comment: 'Be supposed to' gives a nod to an external arbiter of standards, even if only probable public opinion (We're supposed to spend at least two hours on our homework). 'Ought to' references rather a code of ethics or at least known best practice (I ought to eat less fat).

Answer (score 1):

"be supposed to do something", is required to do something because of one may find himself in a situation, or put himself in a situation: agreement, promise, and lack of authority if the usage in negative form: "I am not supposed to remove these books from the reference room". It is an idiomatic expression not a modal.
Modal verbs are must, shall, will, should, would, can, could, may, and might.

*must*, and *have to* are a lot stronger, the strongest is 'must'.
and there is 'should' in between *have to* and *supposed to do.*

You must obey the law.

*shall* expresses strong assertion, and promise in a positive form; 
in the negative, a command, a divine order; *thou shan't steal!*

In the interrogative shall expresses an offer, " Shall I pick you up in the airport?"

*ought to*, comes close to *should,* as it indicates duty, and correctness.

Your usage is by the book.